# User navigating to site in game client gets HTML response from an unknown site

Tags: javascript, http, nw.js

I have an HTML5 game built with NW.js that makes a GET request to my website to retrieve a static data file, `file.json`, hosted at `www.example.com/file.json` on Heroku.

One of my users can navigate to `www.example.com/file.json` and see the file properly, but when they open the game, this request returns HTML from a different site. After over 100,000 users, they are the first one to experience this.

The HTML response the user gets is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980,user-scalable=yes,maximum-scale=2.0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/steal-built/production.css" />

<script src="/js/thirdParty/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/gui/js/jquery-utils.js"></script>
<script src="/gui/js/gui-core.js"></script>
<script src="/gui/js/gui-api.js"></script>

<script src="/js/thirdParty/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/js/thirdParty/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/thirdParty/cssua.js"></script>
<script src="/js/thirdParty/moment.js"></script>

<!--noUI slider plugin: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->
<script src="/js/thirdParty/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>

<!--jquery sort elements plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ -->
<script src="/js/thirdParty/jquery.sortElements.js"></script>

<!-- datepicker plugin: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ -->
<![if gte IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/thirdParty/pickadate.min.js"></script>
<![endif]>

<!-- datepicker: legacy for older browsers -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="/js/thirdParty/pickadate.legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery plugin for parsing CSV file format: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/ -->
<script src="/js/thirdParty/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

<!-- MD5 encryption library -->
<script src="/js/thirdParty/md5.js"></script>

<!--ie polyfill for console.log and related -->
<script src="/js/modemUI/console-polyfill.js"></script>

<script src="/js/thirdParty/dust-full-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/js/thirdParty/dust-helpers-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/thirdParty/raphael.js"></script>

<!-- For calculating subnet masks https://github.com/franksrevenge/IPSubnetCalculator -->
<script src="/js/thirdParty/IPSubnetCalculator.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!--div that is used to identify if the user's browser is (likely) a mobile device. Will be hidden by css, then examined with js-->
    <div id="div-is-smartphone"></div>
    <div id="root-view"></div>
    <!-- IE6 specific style here in case javascript disabled -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><style type="text/css">#init-screen {position: absolute; height: 480px;}</style><![endif]-->
    <!-- if we have no javascript, hide activity-indicator -->
    <noscript><style type="text/css">#init-screen .activity-indicator{display: none}</style></noscript>
    <div id="init-screen">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="title"></div>
            <div class="activity-indicator"></div>
            <div class="error-message">
                <noscript>No javascript / Javascript absent</noscript>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="init-log" style="display: none;">
        <div class="header">
            <span class="close">x</span>
            <span class="title">Initialization Log</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <table></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/steal/steal.production.js?steal-built/production.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, there is no chance that this is being served from my site. Could the user be affected by malware? They said they didn't mess with any configuration files in Windows, but I have my doubts. I checked their request headers, and everything looked completely normal.